# How to create report that is built on multiple objects

Tags: reporting, custom-object, custom-report-type, joined-reports

So I've been given the job to create a report, that compares a **target sales amount** to **actual sales amounts**, and lastly to a **funnel** (which is taken from the SUM of all opportunities Estimated Net Amount), for each sales representative.

I have these 3 amounts in 3 different objects, 2 of them being custom objects that are used heavily.

The main goal is to have a report with a chart, where for each month (or quarter), we can see these 3 columns right next to each other, so we're able to compare the amounts visually.

I tried creating a new Custom Report Type, however I was not able to create the object relationships, since I couldn't pick the right objects from the drop down lists.

**Then I had another idea**: could I possibly collect all the necessary data to a custom object, and just create the report on that single custom object?(without the need to set up any object relationship in the report)

We already have a custom object (which is called QUOTA), which has a Sales Rep, Target (the amount), and a time period set.
Would it be possible to use the Sales Rep and the time period, to get the other data? (For example: all opportunities of the sales rep from the given time period?)

I'm a little new to this, so I'm curious if I'm over complicating things here, and there's actually a really easy way to do this...?

Comment: What's wrong with using Opportunities, Forecasting, and Sales Quotas, all standard objects in Salesforce?

Comment: sfdcfox - I guess that ship has sailed, since the custom objects are already used throughout the organisation. Also, there's definitely need for at least one custom object, in the report, so the question still remains valid, and the need to interconnect that object with the rest is still there.

Comment: Without knowing the overall structure, not sure if this helps, but have you looked at a [Joined Report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_joined_format_concepts.htm&type=5)?

Comment: sfdcfox - After finally being able to activate Joined Reports on the lightning UI, I gave it a swing,  but I quickly bumped into a problem: I can't group by date fields correctly.
Sadly, Joined Reports only allow to group by the fields of the connecting object (which in my case would be a sales rep).
I managed to get the info from both objects, that have the common Sales Rep. The problem is that I can't make a monthly grouping.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Custom Report Type.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003405&type=1

Other way to do same is customization.  You can create Visualforce page where you can use `<apex:chart>`[more](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_chart.htm)
[Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_example.htm)

Comment: Custom Report Types didn't help. When trying to create the object relationships, I wasn't allowed to select the right ones.